# Redirect Loop after header location

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

Good morning, I am dealing with an existing code and I need to solve a problem:
When you write a URL without logging into the Web, you can see the page in question (except the layout), what I need is to redirect to the login to avoid this.
[So you can see the page without logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNN5n.png)

Checking the code I have seen that it is like this:

layout.php

```
<body>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])):?>
    HTML code (Logo, menu...)
<?php else:?>
  <?php 
  View::load("login");
    ?>
<?php endif;?>
</body>
```

If I change "View::load("login");" to "header("Location: index.php"); exit();", it causes an Infinite loop and does not load anything.
I have investigated a lot in Stackoverflow and other websites but I do not find the solution. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

index-view.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h1>LegoBox</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

login-view.php

```
<?php
if(Session::getUID()!=""){
        print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=home';</script>";
}

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password_updated'])):?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i> Se ha cambiado la contraseña exitosamente.</p>
            <p>Pruebe iniciar sesion con su nueva contraseña.</p>

            </div>
        <?php setcookie("password_updated","",time()-18600);
         endif; ?>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" data-background-color="lemon">
      <h4 class="title">Acceder</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content table-responsive">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?view=processlogin">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="mail" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion" style="background-color:#339c24">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

processlogin-view.php

```
<?php
if(Session::getUID()=="") {
$user = $_POST['mail'];
$pass = sha1(md5($_POST['password']));

$base = new Database();
$con = $base->connect();
 $sql = "select * from user where (email= \"".$user."\" or username= \"".$user."\") and password= \"".$pass."\" and is_active=1";
//print $sql;
$query = $con->query($sql);
$found = false;
$userid = null;
while($r = $query->fetch_array()){
    $found = true ;
    $userid = $r['id'];
}

if($found==true) {
//  print $userid;
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$userid;
//  setcookie('userid',$userid);
//  print $_SESSION['userid'];
    print "Cargando ... $user";
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=home';</script>";
}else {
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=login';</script>";
}

}else{
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=home';</script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Well you’d have to see to it that you don’t do this redirect, if what was requested is the index.php already. (Go check what $_SERVER contains, if you are having trouble to get this done.)

Comment: So your login setup is on login.php or index.php because if you set your header to the index and the index requires a login that's where your infinite loop is

Comment: There is really no content in index.php, but when I access the Web from the root URL, what is shown to me is index.php (that is what the URL indicates). But I would swear that what I am being shown is login-view.php, although if I redirect to login-view.php I get 404 error.

Comment: I have edited the question, I added the PHP files related to the login